# Textbox ENTER to save the text to DB -- MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a text box and if user types something and Hit enter it should save it to the DB.

```
 @Html.TextArea("txtComments", new {@style = "width: 450px;",@placeholder = "Enter Comments here" })
```

Basically am looking for an event to fire on ENTER. and am implementing in RAZOR MVC.

i saw few ideas of keeping  and other stuffs. But i thought this is the better place to post it.

Thanks

Comment: What's the use of a textarea when you can't create a newline with Enter?

Comment: i shld change it. i was trying smthn else.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically am looking for an event to fire on ENTER

You could subscribe to the [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event of the textarea and detect if <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed:

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtComments').keypress(function() {
        var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if(code == 13) { 
            // Enter was pressed => act accordingly
        }
    });
});
```

> and am implementing in RAZOR MVC.

Razor is a view engine which runs on the server. You cannot detect key presses on the server. You will have to use client side scripting (javascript) as I have shown previously.